# How to check the document scrollTop?

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

```
if( $('html,body').scrollTop() != 150 ){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 150},'slow');
}
```

I'm trying to check if the height of the scroll is not 150, and if that's true I'd like to move the scroll to 150, How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiya **try this working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/jqj9T/

This will help, Please let me know if I am missing anything,

`scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 150` should do the trick.

**Jquery code**

```
  if ($('html,body').scrollTop() != 150) {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 150
    }, 'slow');
}​
```

Comment: @MohamedSaid No worries bruv, glad it helped!